# Short story anthology - pillow book, moving scenery, big space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I'm trying to find the name of an old collection of short stories I read as a child in the UK in the 1980s.  Unfortunately I only dimly remember it and I have never been able to track it down, so I hope this rings a bell with someone.  There were only three or four stories in it:

One of the stories (I think the first in the book) was called something like: "the pillow book of XYZ" and I think the protagonist was a young girl.

Another of the stories (I think the second) featured space pirates who had landed on an alien planet.  When they went outside their spaceship to look around, the rocks and scenery on the planet moved around when they weren't looking, so they got lost.

The last one I remember very little of but I think it was something to do with a big space station.

Comment: "The Pillow Book of Liisa Härkönen" was published in 2011 in ChiZine.

Comment: It was a long while before that although that sounds like a curious read.  If I had to narrow it down further than "the 80's" I'd say mid-to-late 80s but the book may already have been old then for all I know.

Comment: @user14111 [yes](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1993725)

Comment: Any relationship to [the famous pillow book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pillow_Book)?

Comment: I don't think so, it was sff rather than historical.

Comment: @user14111 While it's possible there was another publication, the author's entry lists publications between 2007 and 2013--1980s seems much too early. His older blog lists 2003 as earliest published story with some spoken word / poetry beginning in 2001.